# C# How to find the right PATTERN for Regex

Tags: c#

Helli I have an config.ini File which contains the string: Health=true or false or nothing.
So Health=true , Health=false, Health=. My question is how the PATTERN have to look like to find one of these.
EDIT: The RegexOptions.Multiline fixed it Like u said - mb, thanks for help <3

```
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\conf.ini");
            
            const string PATTERN = @"Health=(?<value>.*)$";
            Match match = Regex.Match(text, PATTERN, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                int index = match.Groups["value"].Index;
                int lenth = match.Groups["value"].Length;

                text = text.Remove(index, lenth);
                text = text.Insert(index, "test".ToString());
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\conf.ini", text);
                
            }
This does not change Health=value to-> Health=test any ideas?
```

Comment: Would your config.ini have other key value pairs too? Wouldn't Line by Line reading & matching make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex pattern could be: ^Health=(?<value>.*)$

Also, remember to enable Multiline matching option when instantiating Regex object.

So this would work for config file having multiple key value pairs (one per line):

[image]

Comment: Since you want to update config - I would recommend use: File.ReadAllLines() - then process each line one by one and append to a StringBuilder. When Regex matches on a line - Update the string (for that line) before appending to StringBuilder.  Finally take .ToString() from string builder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pattern = (true|false|\.)` if you wanted to match just the values true, false, .